# Submitting a form with Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to use JQuery to submit my form without reloading the page. How can I do this?

My Form:

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</html>
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
    $name= $_POST['name'];
        echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: `$.post("submit.php", $("form").serialize());`

Comment: you should really take a look at the jQuery's ajax method here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: do you mean you don't want the page to load, or do you want the submission to happen without reloading the page that the user is currently on?

Answer (score 2):

As per comments, please refer to the jQuery docs/1000's of tutorials on the matter. 
Nonetheless:

```
$('#form-id').submit(function(){

// work yon javascript magicke

 });
```

Edit: do note this is a non ajax solution for a simple form submit (client side-validation etc.); if you want to get fancy refer to the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

By using ajax :

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url : 'submit.php',
       data: $(this).serialize()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wait until the document has loaded, then interupt the submit event, and run some `ajax`

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

    $( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function ( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/mypage.php',
            data: $( this ).serialize(),
            success: function ( data ) {
                alert( data );
            }
        });

    }):

});
```